# Latin expression for "carrying something on one's back"

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, medieval-latin, spanish, vulgar-latin

In Spanish, the word *[cuesta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BaxmI1N)* is nowadays used as *slope*. Nonetheless, the etymology of the word indicates that it comes fom Latin *[costa, ae](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=costa&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* meaning "a side" but also "a rib". In fact, an old meaning for the Spanish word *cuesta* is "costilla" (Spanish for "rib").

This said, there's this Spanish expression, *llevar algo a cuestas* ("to carry something on one's back"). I have looked for the origin of the expression but it goes as *back* as the 12th century. It appears on the first preserved manuscript of *Cantar de Myo Çid*, so it probably originated before. Given the etymology of *cuesta* as "rib", the sense of the expression would be that of "carrying something over one's ribs". And given that the expression is very old, I wonder:

Did the Latin language have a similar expression, using the word *costa*, to convey the meaning of "carrying something on one's back", either on the classical or medieval periods?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on this? We have various like expressions in English idiom, which may often have no physical reality, for instance _shoulder a burden_ and _put one's back into something_. Is that the kind of thing which you mean?

Comment: @TomCotton not really, the Spanish expression "a cuestas" is quite literal, I just wanted to know if the expression originated in Latin or in Spanish, given how old it is.

Answer (score 4):

An Early, Classical, and Late Latin **synthetic** expression corresponding to Sp. "llevar a cuestas" is the denominal verb *bāiulāre* (see the image below). As for **analytic** variants formed by a verb of motion plus a body part (the ones you appear to be more interested in), I've been unable to find any relevant verb with *costa* 'rib' but, for example, there are quite a few with *dorsum* 'back': e.g., cf. *dorso graviora arma portare* (Curt. V, 13, 8), *pleraque utensilia reportare dorso* (Col. 7, 1, 3), *si dorso libeat cornipedis vehi* (Sen. *Phaed.* 809),  *cum (asellus) gravius dorso subiit onus* (Hor. *Sat* I, 9, 21), etc. Cf. also similar constructions with *humerus* 'shoulder': e.g., *humeris rem publicam sustinere* (Cic. *Flac.* 94).

Since there are many examples of an analytic construction like *aliquid (onus) {dorso/humeris/collo/...} {portare/vehere/subire/...}*, it seems reasonable that such a general constructional pattern could also be applied to the specific analytic correlate in Latin of your Sp. "llevar algo a cuestas", lit. 'to carry something over one's ribs'. There is in fact indirect evidence for the analytic pattern you're searching for with your *costa* 'rib': i.e., '**X moves Y over X's ribs**'. For example, notice that the existing Spanish denominal verb [*acostar(se)*](http://etiblogia.blogspot.com/2018/07/palabras-con-origen-curioso.html) can also be argued to be analyzed as being originally formed from a similar analytic structure like *[**AD COSTAM**](https://books.google.es/books?id=5h7L2fuFQkQC&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=%22AD%20COSTAM%22%20acostar&source=bl&ots=n_zYIppQvi&sig=ACfU3U0a7Ri1teEnj-k8I_fZ3ySB5WuX5Q&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwissIrzifXjAhUxSEEAHe1aAlQQ6AEwCnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22AD%20COSTAM%22%20acostar&f=false) MOVERE*, with the nominal root *cost(a)* 'rib' being incorporated into an abstract verb of motion (i.e., the original meaning of Sp. "acostar(se)" is 'X moves X(se) or Y ***AD*** (i.e, toward) {X/Y}'s ribs'). NB: a similar analytic origin has already been posited for other so-called "parasynthetic verbs" like *adgregare* (cf. *ad gregem ducere*), **ad-ripare* (cf. *ad ripam venire*), etc.

[image]  (source: Gaffiot (1934))